# How to add numbers for one to 8 on the left and righ side of this function

Tags: python, function, numbers, nonetype

Hi I have problem i dont knbwo how to add numbers order 1 to 8 on the left side and right side of this function. And another problem is there is always showing none when I print it I dont know why I thouth it was beacouse my function was empty but that din't help . So what can I do with this thank you very much.

Comment: it's printing None because your function does not return anything. Also what do you mean by adding number on the left and right side of the function? Could you show us the desired output?

Comment: @ Igor Moraru done

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I shortened a bit your code. Mainly replaced multiple if conditions with a replacement map, that you can pass to your function.

```
sachy = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0,2]]
poradi =["_", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "_"]

repl_map = {
    0: ".",
    1: "o",
    2: "*"
}

def sachovnice(repl_map):
    print(" ".join(poradi))  
     
    for i, radek in enumerate(sachy): 
        print(f"{i+1} " + " ".join([repl_map.get(cell) for cell in radek]) + f" {i+1}")
      
    print( " ".join(poradi))       
    
sachovnice(repl_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your own code too much, please see below a fix to it. Igor's approach is a better way to do it, if you can understand what it does.

```py
sachy = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0,2]]
poradi = [" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", " "]

def sachovnice(nula, jedna, dva):
    x = 1
    result = " ".join(poradi) + '\n'

    for radek in sachy:
        result += f"{x} "
        for i in radek:
            if i == nula:
                result += '. '
            elif i == jedna:
                result += 'o '
            elif i == dva:
                result += '* '
        result += f"{x}\n"
        x += 1
    
    result += " ".join(poradi)

    return result


print(sachovnice(0,1,2))
```

Comment: thanks you but I am only in 1 year so I understand your code better and I think teacher would not accept the other one because there are codes that he would not accept because we just started with basic things but still goo dto learn a new things at least thanks